# Find all file occurences of a search term on drive

Tags: c#, performance, io

I have written a small application that lets the user search drives for their given input string. I am only returning the full name of files. What I have now is the following method to retrieve those full names:

```
private IEnumerable<string> FindOccurences(string searchQuery, DriveInfo drive)
{
    return drive.RootDirectory.EnumerateFiles(searchQuery).Select(file => file.FullName);
}
```

Where I made the choice of using `EnumerateFiles` over `GetFiles` to get faster performance as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles methods differ as follows: When you use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of names before the whole collection is returned; when you use GetFiles, you must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and directories, EnumerateFiles can be more efficient.

I was wondering if there is any other solution to increase performance even more, perhaps through a different API? Are there any other tweaks to my code you can suggest?

Answer (score 2):

I really like this code. Let me explain why in a few short sentences:

**Typechoice:**

You return an `IEnumerable` and not a `List`. This is awesome, because a `List` implies sorted entries **and** blocks some Types, that you can use with `IEnumerable`

**Naming:**

Your names are short, comprehensive and follow the naming conventions. There's not much more to say.

**Program flow:**

It is instantly obvious to the reader, what your program does and **how it does that**, simply by speaking english. This is very hard to accomplish, and I want to compliment you on that.

**Choice of methods:**

You explained very nicely why you chose `EnumerateFiles()` over `GetFiles()`. If you'd comment that, IMO your code would be perfect.

Comment: That actually made me feel good, put a smile on my face, thanks! However, my code is, sadly, not entirely working as I expected so some changes will appear that might make it ugly. But the basics are good which is something I was really aiming for. So thank you for reviewing my code!

Answer (score 0):

Can you add `AWAIT/ASYNC` pattern to the caller of `FindOccurences` ?  That might allow you you to draw the names as fast as the iterator returns them.